# What layout to use for relative positioning

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android application and have created a tabbed layout for my application. I want to be able to create a layout on the first tab that looks like this: 
[image: I want to be able to evaluate certain products]

I am just working on Tab 1 for now and the part with the A+ is supposed to just be a random pic that gets uploaded.
How would I go about making a layout like this? 
What layout type should I use?
What would be the most efficient way of making this layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout. Set ImageView that will be below the TabWidget. Then set the TextView for Description to be toRight of your ImageView and below TabWidget, and the Evaluation TextView to be below the ImageView. Hope the words helped :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/main2">
            ///here you make the positioning of imageview and textviews

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Note that this will apply for both of your tabs, if you want to have different views per each tab, then try inflating.

Edit:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activty4TheSecondTab.class);
     spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("2ndtab").setIndicator("MySecondTab",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.something))
                      .setContent(intent);
```

So in the Activty4TheSecondTab.class you set content layout like usual. Do this for both tabs.

Comment: If i don't want it to apply for both of my tabs should i put the relative layout section in the the layout for that specific page

Comment: Then you'll set up TabHos.Spec specificiation for the second tab that will hold the content you want to show. See the edited code above...

Comment: im sort of confused, what is android:id="@+id/main2" main2 supposed to stand for. And do i use the function layout_below="@id/tabWidget" to set the ImageView below it

Comment: No. if you are setting the image view in the  <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/main2">
        /// HERE

            </RelativeLayout>

then you shouldnt put below, leave it as it is. The RelativeLayout itself, is below the tabwidget and you are adding the imageview inside the relativelayout :D

Comment: Everytime i try to use the code given it gives me an error saying that No resource found that matches the given name android:id="@+id/main2"

Comment: delete that line and write it by hand :) and add new id name. :)

Comment: could u possible show me the code on how to add a new id name?? cuz i don't know how to do it i am a noob

Comment: Its not you are noob. Everyone has to go through basics, I did too. 

Do this:    android:id="@+id/HERE-PUT-THE-NAME-YOU-WANT-FOR-THIS-LAYOUT"

Comment: it still gives me the same error No resource found that matches the given name android:id="@+id/simpleMode"

Comment: nvm i found the problem i forgot the + Thank You so much

Answer (score 0):

Read [this tutorial about TabHost in android](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) and flow its instructions if your want. 
In my experience, I will create my own layouts for this. "tab1", "tab2" are buttons with background image. The contain (A+, Description, Evaluation,...) of each tab will be layouted inside a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout, or ...

Hope this help.